# Save Video Stream in Chunks From Camera

Tags: c#, camera, video-streaming, ip-camera, chunking

I currently have a MJPEG camera that I need to capture and save its video in hour intervals.

I have tried to achieve this by chunking the incoming data and saving it all to a file, but the file that is creates is just a corrupted version of the video stream about 1 second long.

Here is what I have

```
request = WebRequest.Create("http://MYVIDEOURL.videostream.cgi");

request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

request.Method = "POST";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

using(var fs = new FileStream(@"C:\TestVideo.avi", FileMode.Create)) {

    using(var repStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {

         while (!bw.CancellationPending)//this is for the background worker
         {

             byte[] b = new byte[4096];

             int bytesRead = repStream.Read(b, 0, b.Length);

             repStream.Read(b, 0, bytesRead);

             fs.Write(b, 0, bytesRead);


         }//end while

         fs.Close();

    }//end using

}//end using
```

All of that is in a backgroundworker and I have a timer in a thread that runs it for the amount of time specified.

This method I am using is connecting to the stream, but as I said only saving one second of video, and the video is corrupted.

Comment: If you are creating .avi file, you will need to create the correct headers, otherwise it will not work. Take a look at some avi library to solve your problem. eg. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".